# Calculating Model Fields from

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I would like to ask a user for a single piece data in a single field inside a CreateView and from that field calculate the values of the remaining model fields.

So instead of asking them for all the data, I can just ask for one thing and calculate the rest.

A basic example:

Model.py

```
class EggCount(models.Model):
    crates = models.IntegerField()
    cartons = models.IntegerField()
    eggs = models.IntegerField()
```

Views.py

```
class EggCountCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    model = models.EggCount
    fields = ['crates']
    template_name = 'egg_form.html'
```

The associated math that I want to use to fill out the 'cartons' and 'eggs' fields in the model.

```
cartons = crates * 50
eggs = cartons * 12
```

Where does this math go in Django? In the model? As part of the form_valid function in the view? Should I keep it separate somehow call it from the model or the view?

Sorry but I am completely lost and having a hard time finding a clear answer to the best approach for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hidden form fields like that in your egg_form.html

`<input type="hidden" name="cartons" value="">
 <input type="hidden" name="eggs" value="">`

and use javascript/jQuery to perform your calculate and store the result in the value attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Kevin. I'm hoping to strictly use Django/Python here. This is a simplified version of what my real code is for the sake of clarity. The real code already has several equations already build in python that I would like to leverage.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of the code, I think you need to do something like this, putting your math functions within the models and then calling them from the view and then doing whatever you need with them:

models.py

```
class EggCount(models.Model):
    crates = models.IntegerField()
    cartons = models.IntegerField()
    eggs = models.IntegerField()

    def cartons(self):
        cartons = self.crates * 50

    def eggs(self):
        eggs = self.cartons * 12
```

views.py

```
class EggCountCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    model = models.EggCount
    fields = ['crates']
    templates_name = 'egg_form.html'
    # call the functions within the view
    cartons = model.cartons()
    eggs = model.eggs()
    #then you can do something with the results
```

Comment: Thanks @pasta1020. This is an interesting approach. I did something similar, but instead of adding to the model I created a services.py file that holds the equations and then that logic gets called on the form_valid from the view. I'm open to hearing counter points as to why this a bad practice though.